# Vagrant file for .NET Developer (with Windows, IIS, MS SQL)

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm looking for Vagrant file which can be used as base for .NET Developers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a [**repository with Vagrantfile**](https://github.com/dmitry-zaets/vagrantfile-windows-iis-mssql) and couple of scripts which use already existing Vagrant box with `Windows 2008 R2 x64 with Service Pack 1` created by [ferventcoder](https://vagrantcloud.com/ferventcoder)

Website of repository with files and scripts: http://dmitry-zaets.github.io/vagrantfile-windows-iis-mssql/

Vagrant file install:

- .NET 4.5;
- IIS 7.5;
- MS SQL Server 2008 R2;

Vagrant file creates:

- Test website on iis (with needed permissions and framework version);
- Test database with test user;

**Feel free to contact me if you need provisioners for any other component!**

Comment: I always get this error:
<f:Message>The WS-Management service cannot process the request. This user is allowed a maximum number of 5 concurrent shells, which has been exceeded. Close existing shells or raise the quota for this user. </f:Message></f:WSManFault> (WinRM::WinRMWSManFault).
Any suggestion?

Comment: This seems to address your concerns. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/27020cf2-47fc-43e3-b135-e68b80a1bb4e/the-wsmanagement-service-cannot-process-the-request?forum=winservercore 

I've also created a github issue https://github.com/dmitry-zaets/vagrantfile-windows-iis-mssql/issues/9